# Module 'FirebaseSessions' not found in xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, crashlytics

While i want to run app flutter from xcode it's print error

```
Module 'FirebaseSessions' not found
```

This issue happened after update to last crashltyics firebase
ou

Answer (score 0):

## Add Flutter session pod

open pod file then add

```
target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

 
   pod 'FirebaseSessions'
 
end
```

## Flutter Clean

open termnial at Android IDE then write:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get 
flutter pub upgrade
```

## xcode pod file

open your termnial of Mac, then make the cd to your project path ios folder
then write this command

```
pod install
pod update
```